# Prevent Cross Site Request Forgery in jQuery Ajax Call

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asmx, csrf

I need help to prevent CSRF to my webservice which calls from jQuery ajax.
I know very little about CSRF and need any sample code to solve this security issue.
I have given here soem sample:
My webmethod (asmx) will be like this:

```
[WebMethod]
public Product GetProducts(string category)
{
    Product product = new Product
    {
        Name = "Product1",
        Price = "1500",
        Size = "A1"
    };

    return product;
    }
public class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Price { get; set; }
    public string Size { get; set; }
}
```

This webmethod I am calling from jQuery Ajax on some event (let's say on click of some control)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#ajaxTest").click(function () {
        GetProducts();
    });
});


GetProducts = function (category) {
$.ajax(
{
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "/Service/Products.asmx/GetProducts",
    data: "{ category: '" + category + "' }",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        $("#product").text(data.d.Name + " " + data.d.Price + " " + data.d.Size);
    },
});
}
```

Now how can I implement CSRF prevention here?
Not sure whether my question is clear, please let me know if anymore details required also please let em know if you have any inputs.

Thanks in advance..!

-Sharath

Comment: After referring different suggestion, and by assumption, this is what I did finally. Not sure how much thsi is correct and how secure my webservice now. Please somebody let me know your comments if there is any loophole or issue in the code.
Created GUID in page load (in master file) and considered it as Token, stored the value in Session and hidden field.
Added Enable session to Webmethod
    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public Product GetProducts(string category)
    {...}
     passed hidden token in ajax header
and then validated the session value with header value passed

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to use the Synchronizer Token Pattern. This simply means generating of random "challenge" tokens that are associated with the user's current session. These challenge tokens are then inserted within the HTML forms and links associated with sensitive server-side operations.

Since you're running ASP.NET, you could use the ViewState feature. View more info here: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: Thanks William for the input